# JavaFX labels height

Tags: java, height, javafx, label, scenebuilder

I'm developing software in JavaFX and JavaFX Scene Builder.

I have a grid pane with 2 columns. Actually in each of the cells there are labels.
In the first column of the table the text inside the label is a default constant, in the second one the text can change.

The problem is that if the text variable is too long, it's automatically truncated.

How to start a new line trimming the text and re-sizing the height of the rows in the grid pane?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @fabian issues, this is the solution to the initial question.
In addiction is necessary to set the fx:id of each element into Scene Builder.

```
@FXML private GridPane gridPane;
@FXML private Text text1;
@FXML private Text text2;
@FXML private Text text3;


private void setGridRowHeight(GridPane gpName, int numRow, double height){
    ObservableList<RowConstraints>  rows = gpName.getRowConstraints();
    rows.get(numRow).setMinHeight(32);
    rows.get(numRow).setPrefHeight(height);
    rows.get(numRow).setMaxHeight(height);
}


private void addTextListener(final GridPane gridPane, final Text text){

    text.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
            text.setWrappingWidth( gridPane.getColumnConstraints().get(1).getPrefWidth() );
            setGridRowHeight(gridPane, gridPane.getRowIndex(text), text.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() );
        }
    });
}


@FXML public void initialize() {
    addTextListener(gridPane, text1);
    addTextListener(gridPane, text2);
    addTextListener(gridPane, text3);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately the `Label` element does not resize depending on the text displayed. I recommend using the [`Text`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) Shape. You can specify the maximal width using wrapping width in the scene builder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've updated my question with the code containing the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
Label col2Label = new Label();
col2Label.setWrapText( true );
col2Label.setMaxHeight( Double.MAX_VALUE );
col_1_Label.prefHeightProperty().bind( col2Label.heightProperty() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap [Region - Label - Region] in HBox.
The region will keep the label always centered.